# Laravel 5.3 Auth block user

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3, laravel-authorization

I have a question, I'm currently developing a little site with Laravel 5.3 and I'm using the Basic Auth from them for users to register and login.

Now I want the following: Everybody can register and login, but if I click on a button (as an admin), I can "block" one specific user (for example if he did something not allowed), I don't completely delete the row in the database, but somehow make sure that if the user tries to login he get's a message saying something like "you can't login any more, your account is blocked, contact admin for more info" or something similar. The question is: Whats the best way to do this? I didn't find something built in, correct me if I'm wrong... 
Ofcourse, I could just alter the users table and add a column called "blocked", set to false normally, then with the button, set it to true and then when logging in somehow checking for this value and (if it's true) showing this message and not allowing log in. Is this the best way to do this? If yes, where would I have to check for this value and how can I show the message then? If not, whats the better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do what you're suggesting - use a `blocked` or `active` column to indicate if the user should be able to log in. When I've done something similar in the past, to check this value upon login, I moved the out-of-the-box login function into my LoginController and added to it a bit. My login method now looks like this:

```
/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->firstOrFail();
    if ( $user && !$user->active ) {
        return $this->sendLockedAccountResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

I also added these functions to handle users who weren't active:

```
/**
 * Get the locked account response instance.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function sendLockedAccountResponse(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->loginUsername() => $this->getLockedAccountMessage(),
        ]);
}

/**
 * Get the locked account message.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getLockedAccountMessage()
{
    return Lang::has('auth.locked')
            ? Lang::get('auth.locked')
            : 'Your account is inactive. Please contact the Support Desk for help.';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks cood what you posted but how can I move the out-of-the box login function into my own controller so it uses what I rpvoide instead?

Comment: The AuthController inherits the login method from `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`. If you copy the login method from that class into your AuthController, Laravel will use the AuthController version instead. That way you can modify it to fit your needs. (this is for Laravel 5.2, but I believe these class names are the same in 5.3)

Comment: but what exactly is the AuthController? Just a new controller I create? When is it called? Sorry, am a bit confused

Comment: Right - sorry, 5.3 changed the name of the controller. If you're using the laravel auth scaffold, you should add the login method to the LoginController (`App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`).

Comment: so what I do is copy the function `login` from `AuthenticateUsers`, overwrite it in the LoginController, adding the if condition you provided as well as adding the two methods (`sendLockedAccountResponse` and `getLockedAccountMessage`, correct? Before doing so, I make sure there's a button that set's the `locked` column in the db to true, is that what you mean?

Comment: In my example the new column is called `active` (and when it's `false`, that user cannot log in), but everything else is correct. I've updated my answer with the full login method to hopefully make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [soft deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#soft-deleting) feature.

> In addition to actually removing records from your database, Eloquent can also "soft delete" models. When models are soft deleted, they are not actually removed from your database. Instead, a  deleted_at attribute is set on the model and inserted into the database. If a model has a non-null  deleted_at value, the model has been soft deleted.

Comment: Would actually be the same I said but just with `deleted_at` attribute instead of a column called `blocked`.. Also I may want to completely delete something in db as well, so that's not what I want I guess

Comment: @nameless soft deleting is exactly what are you looking for. It already has all necessary methods like `forceDelete()`, `withTrashed()`, `trashed()`, `restore()` etc. It also automatically hides 'blocked' users from usual `get()`, `paginate()` etc queries.

Comment: but with soft deleting activated, can I still completely delete users if I wanted to? And how could I then (if a user was soft deleted) check for it when logging in show the message?

Comment: To completely remove the user use `forceDelete()`

Comment: `To permanently remove a soft deleted model from the database, use the forceDelete method:` do I have to soft delete it first then and then use `forceDelete()`?`also still don't no how I can, when a user logs in, check if this account is soft deleted and if yes print this message (actually print it instead of the `this record wasn't found in the db` message)

Comment: In my case i tried so many things to logout a user, by creating middleware like `BlockedUser` and applying that middle ware to my multiauth. but got no luck and this `soft deleting` is perfect solution for me. thanks to @AlexeyMezenin

Answer (score 0):

step1:

```
add new field to the User table called ‘status’ (1:enabled, 0:disabed)
```

step2:

```
to block the web login , in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php add the follwoing function:

/**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return array
 */
 protected function credentials(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
 {
 $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), ‘password’);

return array_add($credentials, ‘status’, ‘1’);
 }
```

Step3:

```
to block the user when using passport authentication ( token ) , in the User.php model add the following function :

public function findForPassport($identifier) {
     return User::orWhere(‘email’, $identifier)->where(‘status’, 1)->first();
     }
```

refer to this link ( tutorial) will help you : https://medium.com/@mshanak/solved-tutorial-laravel-5-3-disable-enable-block-user-login-web-passport-oauth-4bfb74b0c810

Answer (score 0):

There is a package which not only blocks users but also lets you to monitor them before making a decision to block them or not.

**Laravel Surveillance :** https://github.com/neelkanthk/laravel-surveillance

Answer (score -1):

**Solved**: this link ( tutorial) will help you : https://medium.com/@mshanak/solved-tutorial-laravel-5-3-disable-enable-block-user-login-web-passport-oauth-4bfb74b0c810

step1:

```
add new field to the User table called ‘status’ (1:enabled, 0:disabed)
```

step2:

```
to block the web login , in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php add the follwoing function:

/**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return array
 */
 protected function credentials(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
 {
 $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), ‘password’);

return array_add($credentials, ‘status’, ‘1’);
 }
```

Step3:

```
to block the user when using passport authentication ( token ) , in the User.php model add the following function :

public function findForPassport($identifier) {
     return User::orWhere(‘email’, $identifier)->where(‘status’, 1)->first();
     }
```

Done :)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).